# jQuery - Selector to run a function

Tags: jquery, syntax

How would I use the following code to run a function on any div with the class of `.p11button` which also has `display:block`?

```
if (VARIABLE = true) {
    $('div .p11-button').css('display') == 'block'
    FUNCTION HERE
}
```

Comment: Huh? Question makes perfect sense to me. Why are people down-voting and trying to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (VARIABLE) {
  $('div.p11-button').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('display' === 'block');
  }).each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    //FUNCTION HERE
  });
}
```

In your code example you were assigning variable to true in the condition - this would always evaluate to true! Also, the space in your selector means you will select descendents of divs with class p11-button.

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements by their attributes using square brackets:

```
$('div.p11-button[style*="display:block"]').css('color', 'red');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2uE4s/

This will select all `div` elements with the `p11-button` class and include `display:block` in their style attribute (just for example purposes I then change the CSS `color` property for all the selected elements to show that you don't need an `.each()`).

Here is the documentation for selectors in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('div .p11-button').filter('[style*=display:block]').each(/*function*/);
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing square brackets around the `filter` selector to select by attribute: `.filter('[style*=display:block]')`.